# How to create Haptics effect using Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to add haptics to my application same as like If you go to the iPhone device setting and toggle to Airplane mode, it's a very LIGHT Haptic. I want to achieve same effect.

I have done also as below:
https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/blob/master/ios10/HapticFeedback/HapticFeedback/ViewController.cs

But it's not working!

```
partial void ImpactAction(Foundation.NSObject sender)
{
    // Initialize feedback
    var impact = new UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(UIImpactFeedbackStyle.Heavy);
    impact.Prepare();

    // Trigger feedback
    impact.ImpactOccurred();
}
```

Comment: are you actually calling ImpactAction from somewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes I'm calling it using: ImpactAction(btnToggle);

Comment: When you say it is "not working", what exactly it not working? The expected level of feedback?, no feedback at all? what device model are you trying it on? etc...

Comment: no feedback at all! @SushiHangover

Comment: @Divyesh_008 You did not state which device this is... Does it have a Taptic Engine? If not have you tried using a UIFeedbackGenerator instead...also you can check via UIDevice what type of feedback support the device has...

Comment: I'm using it on iPhone 6 and iPhone 7 device. Is it only work with iPhone-X and Xs-Max? as i said, I cab feel the haptics when i toggle airplane mode button from device settings which same i want to create. I have use haptics like this but its not giving any results! @SushiHangover

Comment: @Divyesh_008 iPhone "6s" and "6s PLUS" intro'd the first haptic engine (much "weaker" in its output force), but the 7 introduced a bigger activator as it had to simulate a "home button" press, see my answer on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test to see if the device has a haptic engine and adjust your feedback accordingly:

```
switch ((UIDevice.CurrentDevice.ValueForKey(new NSString("_feedbackSupportLevel")) as NSNumber).Int16Value)
{
    case 1:
        using (var feedback = new UISelectionFeedbackGenerator())
        {
            feedback.SelectionChanged();
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        using (var feedback = new UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(UIImpactFeedbackStyle.Heavy))
        {
            feedback.ImpactOccurred();
        }
        break;
    default:
        SystemSound.Vibrate.PlayAlertSound();
        break;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, it's working!!, Thank you #SushiHangover!!